# html.twig file will not be rendered/overwritten in Shopware6

Tags: twig, shopware6

If I try, overwrite properties.html.twig in Shopware6 like this, everything works fine

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/page/product-detail/properties.html.twig' %}
{% block page_product_detail_properties_table %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            {% for item in page.product.price.elements %}
            {% set value=item.gross-0.15*item.gross %}
            <p>Der Mindestpreis der letzen 30 Tage lag bei {{ value|round(2,'floor') }} €*<br/>
                {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

If I try same thing with file offcanvas.html.twig like this, content will not be rendered.

What am I doing wrong?

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/component/checkout/offcanvas-cart.html.twig' %}
          {% block component_offcanvas_cart_header_item_counter %}
              {{ parent() }}
              <small class="offcanvas-cart-header-count">
              !!Test!!
              {% if isCartNotEmpty %}
              <div class="col-auto">
                  <p>!!Test!!</p>
                  <small class="offcanvas-cart-header-count">
                      {{ "checkout.itemCounter"|trans({'%count%': checkoutItemCounter})|sw_sanitize }}
                  </small>
              </div>
          {% endblock %}
```

File, which will not be rendered is in folder:
-pluginroot-\custom\plugins\WtMinQuanSurch\src\Resources\views\storefront\component\checkout\ovvcanvas-cart.html.twig

Comment: Thread can be closed as it is answered!

Answer (score 0):

Got it for my own. I had to fire cache:clear in /bin/console of project folder!